# Does the browser you use increase/decrease your download/internet speed?

Tags: internet, browser, speed

I've read on here that download speed isn't affected by the browser you use, so can someone explain the below info for me? Having run a speed test on speedtest.net, you see that the results using Internet Explorer were far slower than using Firefox.

Ping: 15 ms

Download Speed: 8.54 Mbps

Upload Speed: 5.91 Mbps

And here are the results (which are consistent) using Firefox:

Ping: 10 ms

Download Speed: 30.1- Mbps

Upload Speed: 6.01 Mbps

Comment: How do you make the relation from ping to the installed/used browser?

Comment: Probably by visiting website like speedtest.net using different browsers. A lot users make this mistake

Answer (score 2):

Browsers do not affect the bandwidth.  They are completely independent of each other.

Your data makes no sense.  However, I do have an idea.  Speedtest.net will ping servers in your area to find the one with the lowest latency to do a test.  I suspect, their might have been network congestion and the IE test went to a further/slower server to test from.

Run the tests again and be sure to pick the same server/location.

Answer (score 1):

You can be pretty sure that **the browser you use cann't influence the internet speed** you have.
Another thing is, how fast can your browser **show** the transmitted HTML text, pictures or video files.
You can try to speed-up your browser, take a look: http://www.wikihow.com/Speed-up-Browsers

Using this hints you can improve the speed of your current browser but not your internet speed.